# require() in large, multi-file Node projects

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a large Node project. Naturally, I want to break this into multiple source files. There are many modules from the standard lib that I use in a majority of my source files, and there are also quite a few of my own files that I want to use almost everywhere.

I've been making this work by including a huge `require` block at the beginning of each source file, but this feels awfully redundant. Is there a better way to do this? Or is this an intended consequence of Node's admirable module system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a couple of things, here.

First, if so many of your files are requiring the same libraries over and over again, you might want to step back and determine if you're really breaking your code up in the proper way. Perhaps there's a better organization where certain libraries are only needed by subsets of your source files?

Second, remember that the `global` object is shared between all of your `require`d files in your Node.js app. Your "root" source file, say `index.js`, can do things like `global.fs = require('fs');` and then it's accessible from all of your various files. This would eliminate the need to `require` a file full of `require`s. (In Node.js, you have to explicitly state that you're accessing a global variable by prepending `global.`, unlike in the browser.)

This can be a good idea for CRUD-type Express apps where you have lots of code for controllers that are all almost the same but have to be slightly different for each view and you just want to split them apart not for any particular organization structure, but just to make it easier to debug (error in this file, not that file). If the structure of the app is more complex than that, take the usual warnings against global variables to heart before using that trick.

Comment: node.js has cached all the required file, no file would be loaded twice if already in cache. I don't think `global` is necessary.

Comment: I understand that (that's the whole point of modules versus C-style includes), but the question is specifically asking if there is a way to keep the code DRY-er than it currently is by removing superfluous ``require`` statements. ``global`` is one such possibility to do so.

Comment: but `global` leaks of namespace, and you have to make sure the object requested is cached in it.  I think using C-style includes is a wonderful method for each module's files.

Comment: In Node.js's case, all ``global`` objects are restricted to the ``global`` namespace, so it's not as leaky as in browser-based Javascript. I agree that simply prefacing your source files with all of their ``require``d modules is best, but the question author stated that he's simply ``require``-ing a series of the exact same ``require`` modules on every file, which either means he's not organizating his code well if they all need all of those modules, or he's already being lazy and ``require``-ing things he doesn't need. I recommended source cleanup first, and if not that, then ``global``.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a *container* module to load a series of modules. For example, given the following project structure:

```
lib/
    index.js
    module1.js
    module2.js
main.js
```

You can have `index.js` import the other modules in the library.

```
# index.js
module.exports.module1 = require('./module1');
module.exports.module2 = require('./module2');
```

Then `main.js` need only import a single module:

```
# main.js
var lib = require('./lib');

lib.module1.doSomething();
lib.module2.doSomethingElse();
```

This technique can be expanded, reducing redundant imports.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say generally that a require block is better practice than using global in Node.

You need to remember that requires are cached so when you put them in all of your code modules, you will always get the same instance not a new one each time.

Doing it this way ensures that you get the appropriate code with the expected name spaces exactly where you want it whereas using global will include things you don't need. Doing it the Node way with require will also tend to make your code slightly more portable.

Answer (score 0):

Require more than one file without absolute path through require-file-directory.

1- Can require more than one file in single statement.
2- Can require files with only their name.

Visit for solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-file-directory