# Is there a good way to globally require node modules?

Tags: node.js

Is it a bad idea to require modules globally and if so, is there a way to require modules across multiple project files without explicitly requiring them in each file?

I'm assuming the answers is "yes" to the first and "no" to the second but would like to confirm.

This is why I'm asking:

I'm working on a Node project in which there are a few modules(like mongoose) which I'm using in almost every file. I'd like to avoid explicitly requiring these in each file. The only solution I've come up with is to require modules globally (i.e. in my `app.js` file doing this: `mongoose = require('mongoose');` instead of `var mongoose = require('Mongoose');`) but I'm assuming this is bad practice since declaring global variables is... bad.

Comment: You do know that the modules are cached right? Or is style your concern?

Comment: Yes, I've heard that. Style is the concern. Trying to keep things 'dry'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [require() in large, multi-file Node projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612051/require-in-large-multi-file-node-projects)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, globals are bad and the programming community at large has embraced avoidance of global variables as a sound practice. If you do this, everyone who ever looks at your code is going to do a massive facepalm immediately.

But yes, you can create globals just by omitting the `var` keyword as your example indicates.

Don't Repeat Yourself is about code, not about dependency declaration.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was assuming. I actually just flagged this as a duplicate. I do however think that it is repetitive to have to require the same include statement across multiple files. It seems it would be convenient if you could include or require a literal code block from another file or just the contents of a file directly into another file however I assume the creators of Node probably have good reason for not allowing this.

Comment: Note this is not just node. It's also python and many other languages. You might look into Ruby if this sort of thing appeals to you.